# Use template variable within a log query in Datadog

Tags: datadog, template-variables

In my LogStream widget I've the following log query

```
host:"/aws-glue/app/r/jobs/job_name"
```

[image]

the **r** letter should be variable based on the environment, thus I introduced a template variable **$env_tag**
[image]

```
host:"/aws-glue/app/$env_tag.value/jobs/job_name"
```

But it doesn't work ! how can we use template variable inside the query ? Thanks

Comment: even `host:/aws-glue/app/$env_tag.value/jobs/job_name` doesn't work

Comment: Not sure if this is feasible, I'd put as a query something like `host:("/aws-glue/app/jobs/job_name" OR "/aws-glue/app/r/jobs/job_name" $host` with the template variable being the name of the host.

Comment: @XYZ123 unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: It seems that we can't use a variable to filter based on the host, to encouter this, As a quick solution I used to add the env information inside the message thus we can filter only the messages of a specific environment
`(host:"/aws-glue/app/r/jobs/job_name" OR host:"/aws-glue/app/x/jobs/job_name") message:($env.value)`

Comment: So I notice I missed a parenthesis in my query `host:("/aws-glue/app/jobs/job_name" OR "/aws-glue/app/r/jobs/job_name") $host` I tested it on my side and it worked. Your template variable should be `host` and not `@host` is that the case?

Comment: my template variable is called `env_tag`